# Async Framework TaskEx.Delay issue

Tags: c#, frameworks, asynchronous

I've found out some kind of issue when calling TaskEx.Delay with Async Framework CTP in C#

```
public async Task<string> TestAsync() {
    return await TaskEx.RunEx<string>( async () => { //in real app this is time consuming code so this line is so complex 
            await TaskEx.Delay( 1000 );
            return "test;
        } );
}

public async void Test {
    var count = 0;
    while( count < 100 ) {
        var val = await TestAsync();
        Console.WriteLine( val ); // in real app this line adds elements to observable collection binded to ListBox
        count++;
    }
}
```

Output on the console appears mostly once (sometimes two or three times) but not 100 times like i'd expected.

**EDIT:**

It's not console application (code above is simplified) it's WP7 app. Without using Delay it works fine.

Comment: This isn't the actual code you're running - you've got await in a non-async method. If you could come up with a short but *complete* program, it would really help. I don't have access to a compiler at the moment, but with a complete app, I could at least have more of a chance of diagnosing what's going on.

Comment: If you believe there's something wrong with TaskEx.Delay, then try to show it in a console app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure - open sample project (C# Windows Phone) Netflix from Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP bundle. Add await TaskEd.Delay (1000) in LoadMoviesAsync in MainPage.xaml.cs around 78 line right below imageCount += movies.Length; and change pageCount to 2 to see results better. Launch the app enter 2000 in year box and move items on list up and down. After some time items will stop loading but there are still hundreds of them left. Remove Delay and there is no problem!

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to the fact that you're running in a Console application, and not a Windows application.

Async behaves differently in a console application than it does in a Windows Forms, WPF, or WCF application, since there is no synchronization context in place.  As such, the await posts back onto a threadpool thread, and doesn't actually "await" execution.

If you run this in a WPF or Windows Forms app, it will behave as expected.

---

On a side note, your method is overly complex.  You can just do:

```
public async Task<string> TestAsync() {
    await TaskEx.Delay( 1000 );
    return "test";
}
```

This will, effectively, work the same way as your previous method, but with much less overhead (and is far simpler).

Comment: I think it's misleading to say "async doesn't work as expected in a console application" because that clearly depends on your expectations. Async works exactly as *I* expect it to in a console app, which is where I do most of my testing :) The sample code is currently incomplete, but could easily be run in a reasonable way in a console app.

Comment: @Jon: Async and await's behavior within a console mode application is so dramatically different than in a Windows Forms, WPF, WCF, etc, application (unless, of course, you install a custom synchronization context).  The normal guidance of what happens changes dramatically, as thread synchronization and many issues come into play.  Yes, it's perfectly possible to write a reasonable console mode application using async, but it requires you to really pay attention to what you're doing.

Comment: Yup. It's actually pretty easy to do this in a console app - all you need to do is either wait forever (until you get bored) or wait on a task returned from an async method. But yes, it's different. I haven't looked at how a WCF service behaves - I'd have *expected* it to be thread-agile, i.e. use the thread pool - but I haven't tested it. It would certainly be *nice* to be able to write server-side code which didn't care which thread each step ran on.

Comment: @Jon: WCF installs a synchronization context into the call, so it behaves much more like windows forms.  By default, each service call gets run on it's own thread (with its own context), so this works quite well, and you don't have to worry about thread synchronization.  If you change the concurrency mode of the service, this can be different, but that's the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the method `Test` is really and truly an asynchronous method.  The C# compiler just lets you hide this by having a `void` return type.  So if your main method looks like the following

```
public static void Main() {
  Test();
}
```

Then it's not actually running `Test` and waiting for it to fully complete.  It's instead really scheduling `Test` to run and it's completion will happen at some point in the future.  So it makes sense that you see differing outputs because it's timing related.